# MySQL Workbench on Ubuntu 12.04 doesn't start

Tags: mysql-workbench, ubuntu-12.04

MySQL Workbench was working fine till today. I installed the regular updates and now it just doesn't start. When started it just shows the opening screen and nothing happens.

I tried re-installing it from synaptic but no luck. I use it all the time and now suffering a lot. Any help will be appreciated.

When run from terminal with:

```
mysql-workbench --log-level=debug3 --verbose
```

it gives a long log. Please see at: http://pastebin.com/Z2t8pdZF

I see these error in the log but don't know what they mean and how it stopped working automatically:

> /home/atul/.mysql/workbench/wb_state.xml:1: parser error : Document is empty
>
> ^ /home/atul/.mysql/workbench/wb_state.xml:1: parser error : Start tag expected, '<' not found
>
> ^ /home/atul/.mysql/workbench/user_starters.xml:1: parser error : Document is empty
>
> ^ /home/atul/.mysql/workbench/user_starters.xml:1: parser error : Start tag expected, '<' not found
>
> ^ /home/atul/.mysql/workbench/starters_settings.xml:1: parser error : Document is empty
>
> ^ /home/atul/.mysql/workbench/starters_settings.xml:1: parser error : Start tag expected, '<' not found

Comment: Try to move the question to serverfault.com. That one may be more relevant.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

delete the file wb_options.xml and then give a try.

Refer
http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=64087

Answer (score 5):

Just delete `wb_options.xml` inside `/home/<your username>/.mysql/workbench/` folder.

This fixes the issue and moreover all your data residing in your database is still there.

This is definitely a better option than re-installing mysql-workbench again.

Answer (score 1):

Canonical and God knows what went wrong. But here is a fix:

Download:

For 64 bit systems: http://launchpadlibrarian.net/56565535/libzip1_0.9-3ubuntu0.1_amd64.deb

For 32 bit systems: http://launchpadlibrarian.net/56565266/libzip1_0.9-3ubuntu0.1_i386.deb

Once downloaded, double click to install.

Now Download the latest version of My SQL workbench, Its for 11.10 but will work on 12.04. Make sure you download the version (32bit or 64 bit) suitable to you: http://www.mysql.com/downloads/workbench/#downloads

Once downloaded, double click on it to install.

And you are done.